# Cannot read propery getRiders of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, undefined

I want to call a service which I defined in `DeliverService`  but when I called it from controller it gives an error of `Cannot read propery getRiders of undefined` , NO idea why this happened :|

**DeliverService.js**

```
angular.module('Deliver')
    .service('DeliverService', ['$http', '$state', '$resource', '$q', 'SettingService', '$localStorage', "MessageService", function($http, $state, $resource, $q, SettingService, $localStorage, MessageService) {
        var service = { 
            getRiders : function(){
                return $http.get("Hero.json");
                //return $http.get(SettingService.baseUrl + "api/orders");
            } }
        return service;
    }]);
```

**DeliverCtrl.js**

```
use strict';
angular.module('Deliver').controller('DeliverCtrl',['$scope','$state', "SettingService","DeliverService", function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService, SettingService,DeliverService) {
  $scope.riders = [];
  DeliverService.getRiders().then(function(response){
    $scope.riders = response.data.data;
  }, function(error){ 
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies aren't in the matching order here. Hence, `DeliverService` isn't actually injected.

Your controller code should look something like this:

```
angular.module('Deliver').controller('DeliverCtrl', 
  ['$scope','$state', '$ionicModal', 'MessageService', 'SettingService','DeliverService', 
  function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService, SettingService, DeliverService) {
    $scope.riders = [];
    DeliverService.getRiders().then(function(response){
      $scope.riders = response.data.data;
    }, function(error){});
}]);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much you save my day

Comment: @mariasalahuddin glad that helped! :)
 You can accept the answer once timer goes off so that it could help others too

Comment: Sure I will Insha'Allah

Answer (score 1):

In DeliverCtrl.js

The injection Parameter and function parameters do not match

It should be like this

```
['$scope','$state','$ionicModal','MessageService','SettingService','DeliverService', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService, SettingService,DeliverService)
```